# How a child component can get several props/data from two separate parent components

Tags: reactjs, components, parameter-passing, react-props

In one component, why can't I receive two/multiple props from separate components?

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: props.name is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I tried to do it -

```js
function Welcome() {
  const [searchString, setString] = useState('');
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Header name={searchString} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
const [numbers,setNumbers] =  useState('');
retrun(
<Header moneyAmount={numbers} />
)
}

function Header(props) {
return(
<div>
{props.name}
{props.moneyAmount}
</div>
)
}
```

All tries this way or as `function Header({name, moneyAmount}){}`
field.

Is there's a way with `createContext` or `useContext` ?
I tried with `useContext` but I think it's collide  with the `props`, still gives an error.

Comment: You're creating two separate React Elements. One has just the `name` prop and the other has just the `moneyAmount` prop. I'm not sure I understand your question, but React Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) might be helpful also. If your `Home` component is inside of `App` (or vice versa), you could pass the prop from `App` to `Home` and have it pass it to `Header`

Comment: It's still gives an error with `createContext` maybe its collide with the props  `Header` is getting, I don't get why.

Answer (score 1):

You've 3 components: Welcome, Home and Header

Welcome is using the Header component and passing it a `name` prop, so it will only render the name you passed (which you gave the wrong variable, should be `name={searchString}` instead of `name={setString}`).

Home is also using the Header component and passing it a `moneyAmount` prop,
so it will only render the moneyAmount variable.

Welcome and Home have no relation, so the Header component in each one of them dosen't know about the props passed from the other. If you want to pass multiple variables, you must pass directly to the component like so:

```
function Home(props) {
  const [numbers,setNumbers] =  useState('');
  return (
    <Header moneyAmount={numbers} name={prop.searchString} />
  )
}
```

If you want to pass data to a child from 2 different components, you do it like so:

```
function Welcome() {
  const [searchString, setString] = useState('');
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Home name={searchString} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Home(props) {
  const [numbers,setNumbers] =  useState('');
  return (
    <Header moneyAmount={numbers} name={props.name} />
  )
}

function Header(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      {props.name}
      {props.moneyAmount}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel, but is there a way to pass a child **data** from two parents? there must be something.

Comment: @Ileh I edited the answer with the code to do so, if you think my answer helped you, please mark it as Accepted